# How to for loop on pandas dataframe by grouping the values by dates then extracting the filtered group to be saved as a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I've been trying to find out how I can efficiently group the rows in my dataframe using a for loop based on the column ' Date (UTC)'. For every similar date, I need to extract all the rows with that date and save it to a new dataframe. Below is the sample of my data.

```
data = pd.read_csv('MasterData.csv')
print(data)

    Date (UTC)    Magnitude    Vector Station
0   2020-01-05    26.474679 -0.730455   A
1   2020-01-05    30.746291  0.020503   B
2   2020-01-05    37.829401  0.252316   C
3   2020-01-05  1904.611372  0.977388   D
4   2020-01-19    38.441813 -0.044736   B
5   2020-01-19    31.067455  0.419826   C
6   2020-01-19    15.972198 -0.592661   A
7   2020-01-19  1261.038155  0.977394   D
8   2020-02-02    36.628855  0.518991   B
9   2020-02-02    29.724500 -0.818267   A
10  2020-02-02   673.138440  0.977481   D
11  2020-02-02    13.119385  0.327124   C
12  2020-02-16     7.864772  0.311480   C
13  2020-02-16   312.438088  0.977436   D
14  2020-02-16     7.422883 -0.735439   A
15  2020-02-16    30.693853  0.079296   B
16  2020-02-16     4.722992 -0.434787   E
17  2020-03-01    27.501789  0.393106   C
18  2020-03-01   479.118903  0.977505   D
19  2020-03-01    10.022614 -0.887412   A
20  2020-03-01     4.171703 -0.338138   E
21  2020-03-01    26.057769  0.307710   B
22  2020-03-15   580.257861  0.977406   D
23  2020-03-15    17.528845 -0.927358   A
24  2020-03-15     2.963810  0.222188   E
25  2020-03-15    17.535629 -0.052694   B
26  2020-03-15    38.560337  0.283103   C
27  2020-03-29   943.100243  0.977399   D
28  2020-03-29    36.560799 -0.105109   B
29  2020-03-29    17.055374 -0.677127   A
30  2020-03-29     4.614302 -0.315060   E
31  2020-04-12  1095.538437  0.977369   D
32  2020-04-12     6.650060  0.660921   E
33  2020-04-12    55.495947 -0.316548   B
34  2020-04-12    16.269334 -0.614226   A

print(data.dtypes)

 Date (UTC)     object
Magnitude      float64
Vector         float64
Station         object
dtype: object
```

The expected output is that for every new dataframe saved from the filtered data, I need to plot the magnitude and vector of all the stations in a given date using matplotlib quiver.

Comment: What's expected output?

Comment: Hint: 1. search pandas documentation for `groupby` 2. try to iterate over the `GroupBy` object produced by the groupby method. Then you will be able to show your efforts here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to create an empty dictionary and then group the dates into groups and do a loop process.

```
df_dict = {}
for name, group in df.groupby('Date_UTC'):
    df_dict[name] = group

df_dict.values()
    dict_values([    Date_UTC    Magnitude Vector Station
0 2020-01-05    26.474679     -0.730455A
1 2020-01-05    30.746291      0.020503B
2 2020-01-05    37.829401      0.252316C
3 2020-01-05  1904.611372      0.977388D,     Date_UTC    Magnitude Vector Station
4 2020-01-19    38.441813     -0.044736B
5 2020-01-19    31.067455      0.419826C
6 2020-01-19    15.972198     -0.592661A
7 2020-01-19  1261.038155      0.977394D,      Date_UTC   Magnitude Vector Station
 ...])
```

You can also get simply grouping

```
for name, group in df.groupby('Date_UTC'):
    print('split_date:', name)
    print(group)

    split_date: 2020-01-05 00:00:00
    Date_UTC    Magnitude Vector Station
0 2020-01-05    26.474679     -0.730455A
1 2020-01-05    30.746291      0.020503B
2 2020-01-05    37.829401      0.252316C
3 2020-01-05  1904.611372      0.977388D
split_date: 2020-01-19 00:00:00
    Date_UTC    Magnitude Vector Station
4 2020-01-19    38.441813     -0.044736B
5 2020-01-19    31.067455      0.419826C
6 2020-01-19    15.972198     -0.592661A
7 2020-01-19  1261.038155      0.977394D
....
```

Create dataframe

```
df_list = ['df_0','df_1','df_2','df_3','df_4','df_5','df_6','df_7']
i = 0
for name, group in df.groupby('Date_UTC'):
    df_list[i] = group
    i += 1

df_0
    Date_UTC    Magnitude   Vector Station
0   2020-01-05  26.474679   -0.730455A
1   2020-01-05  30.746291   0.020503B
2   2020-01-05  37.829401   0.252316C
3   2020-01-05  1904.611372 0.977388D
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, @r-beginners. I tried both methods and I think I'd go with the second one. But how will I extract the magnitude and vectors of each station by the split_date as I will have to plot it using matplotlib quiver.

Comment: You can make a list of names for each data frame and assign `group` to it. The code has been modified. I have no experience in creating that graph so I can't answer it. Why don't you ask about that graph again? Is this answer acceptable to you?

Comment: Since this is only a sample data, for now we can say that we have grouped 8 different dataframes but in the future once we run this script for automation, we won't know how many groups we will have. How are we going to put that in the df_list?

Comment: I think it can be judged by how many unique dates and times the group is based on. For example, you can use `df['Date_UTC'].unique()` to determine the number of groups. So create a number of groups with DF names.

Comment: Thanks for all the help @r-beginners :) I already have a workaround with the saving of the dataframes